# I have two tables in mysql in which i want to query in mysql as follows

Tags: mysql, sql

table - emp

```
ename | sal  | deptno
-----------------------
smith | 800  | 20
allen | 1600 | 30
ward  | 1400 | 30
jones | 1200 | 20
```

---

table - dept

```
deptno | dname
----------------
20     | Accounting
30     | Sales
```

i want the following output which displays average salary of each department

```
deptno| dname     | avg(sal)
-----------------------------
20    | Accounting| 1000
30    | Sales     | 1500
```

i have tried the query 
select emp.deptno, dname, avg(sal) from emp,dept group by (emp.deptno);

but it is showing error dept.dname' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use avg() and group by

```
select  a.deptno, a.dname, avg(b.sal)
from dept a 
inner  join emp b on a.deptno = b.deptno
group by   a.deptno, a.dname
```